# How to stop process from hogging port 8080?

Tags: linux, process, port

I am trying to use port 8080, but there is a process that keeps using it, and whenever I kill it, another one takes its place.
Here is the result of `sudo netstat -naptu | grep 8080`

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13813/java`

And here is the result of `lsof -i :8080`

`java    13813 alhuang  176u  IPv4 230057448      0t0  TCP *:webcache (LISTEN)`

If I do `kill -9 13813` or `fuser -k 8080/tcp`, after a few seconds, another process (everything the same except PID) takes its place. How can I kill off this process once and for all to free up port 8080?

Comment: you will have to configure the other service to use a different port. there isn't another good solution to this problem.

Comment: Do you know how to figure out what service it is? I have no idea which service is using it.

Comment: I don't believe so.

Comment: 1) What is the _parent_ process of this service (find the PPID from `ps j <pid>` and check its command line)? 2) What does `systemctl status -n0 <pid>` report for the Java process?

Comment: I ended up just trying a reboot, which fixed the issue!